# スリープ時も加速度センサの値を取得できるようにしたい

Tags: android

現在、android studioでセンサ取得のアプリを開発しています。

そこでは、サービスを用いてバックグラウンドでもセンサ値を取得できるようにしたいのですが、スリープモードにすると1分ほどで取得が不可能になってしまいました。

解決策を知っている方がいましたら回答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 対処済みかもしれませんが、この辺の記事が参考になるかも。[Androidでどんな時でもセンサ値を収集し続けられるようにする方法](https://qiita.com/KoheiKanagu/items/20243f9f8e777818c74e), [AndroidOpenTextbook/articles/sensor-01.re](https://github.com/TechBooster/AndroidOpenTextbook/blob/master/articles/sensor-01.re), [Androidのセンサ情報を低消費電力に取得する(Sensor Batching)](https://qiita.com/piyonakajima/items/20007405672b483a3f28), [Androidでスリープ状態で歩数計センサー（TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR）の使用について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34647/26370)

Answer (score 1):

下記が参考になりませんか？

スリープ時にもBroadcastを処理する方法
https://qiita.com/nein37/items/52523e39932323ebc654

Comment: ありがとうございます！